# Objective-C: Force a class to be a subclass of other

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

B is subclass of A. C is a subclass of A.  When i create c i do  `if((self = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:…])) { }` inside the .m in C.

So despite i set the the superclass in C.h to be B (which is what i want), when i create the C object from `unarchiveObjectWithFile:` since this object is subclass of A, i can’t force it to be subclass of B. (Hard to explain sorry).

Is there any workaround ???

In other words: when i `unarchiveObjectWithFile:…` an object that pertains to a class A, and i have another class B that is subclass of A, can the `unarchiveObjectWithFile:` be a subclass of B? (wich is allowed since B is subclass of a)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly: No.

If you archive an instance of `B` then when you unarchive it you get an instance of `B`, likewise for instances of `A` and `C`.

However, in non-technical language, a subclass is everything its superclass is *plus* some extra bits. You can't[*] take an instance of a superclass, created directly or from unarchiving, and make it into an instance of one of its subclasses - the "extra bits" are not there.

HTH

[*] Before someone comments: Yes, this is not absolutely true in all situations, but you are entering obscure, highly specialised, and dangerous waters. Don't go there.

**Addendum**

Seems you might be in the category where changing the class of an object is safe: you should be able to change the class of an instance to a subclass **provided** the subclass adds no instance variables or properties. To do this you can use the [Objective-C runtime functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html):

```
id obj = ... some instance of class A
object_setClass(obj, [B class]); // where B is a subclass of A which adds no properties or variables
```

You can also use the unarchiving classes to set the class.

**Do not do this casually. Consider alternatives, but sometimes it is an appropriate solution.**

Comment: @user588125 - It does sound like you have one of those cases where you can safely change the class, if so go do that with the runtime functions. You can also consider using a category which can be used to replace methods (as opposed to overriding them) - again an area to be careful in.

Comment: Two comments 1: object_setClass doesnt exits in my envrioment, i can't type that without error, i just get object_getClassName(id obj) but _setClass doesnt exist. 2: This solution is not for me. Here i paste what the problem is http://pastebin.com/M1aGZ7S3 . I have a SKEmitterNode that i create with XCode Buildin tool, so when i unarchive it i get a SKEmitterNode (A), but all my SKEmitterNode's that i unarchive has SOME PROPERTIES  and other stuff THEY SHARE, so i created a Emitter:SKSpriteNode (B) to share that functinoality, and in the end i create  Smoke:Emitter (C) and do [[C alloc] init]

Comment: @user588125 - Re comment 1: `object_setClass` is a standard function in the runtime, do you have `#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>`?

Comment: Now i can see the function. Thx! Anyway the problem continues, but at this point i'm considering asking it again with the problem

Comment: @user588125 - Re comment 2: It does appear the Addendum doesn't apply in your case, and you cannot use `object_setClass` as your subclass adds properties.

Comment: I see, so what will you do in this situation? Categories will be a good solution if theres no properties.

Comment: @user588125 - Good idea, ask a new question providing more detail of your exact problem.

Comment: CRD, instead of doing A:SKEmitterNode, B:A C:B i will do: B:NSObject C:B and then a pointer inside B with the SKEmitterNode (Composition). Will be a good hack

Answer (score 1):

The unarchiver wants to create the same type of class that was perviously archived, and that's generally what you want too.

You could look at using `setClass:forClassName:` to change the class that will be unarchived, but you stand a good chance of ruining everything sooner or later...

---

Based on the particle comment:

Another option is to take the superclass instance and 'wrap' it in your subclass instance. So, you can archive and unarchive your subclass instance and it will contain the superclass instance. Any method that your subclass doesn't directly respond to you can forward on to the superclass instance.

In this way you have 2 objects but you aren't tampering with anything or relying on implementation details of classes that you don't own.

Comment: Ok i explain it better: I have created a Particle Emitter with XCode Build in tool, wich DOESNT allow me to change the class of it (i will put instead of SKEmitterNode(A) a subclass of it(B).) Then when i unarchive it i get an instance of A, but i have some functionality to add to those emitters.

Comment: Interesting... So your subclass just adds / overrides some methods? No new properties / instance variables? Give `setClass:forClassName:` a try, but be defensive with your coding. I'm going to update my answer with a different option though...

Comment: Yes, just adds some methods, anyway, i dont know how to use `setClass:forClassName:` here! http://pastebin.com/9i4TpUAA

Comment: You would create the unarchiver and then, before it starts unarchiving: `[unarchiver setClass:[Emitter class] forClassName:NSStringFromClass([SKEmitterNode class])]` --- if `SKEmitterNode` is part of a class cluster now, or any time in the future, you will have problems, hence this isn't recommended!